# Can a Parameterized Hudson Build Override the svn revision?

Tags: build, hudson

I'd like to setup the ability to rebuild from a specific revision.  The default would be HEAD and a user could rebuild an old build (that had been removed).  I'd still like to leverage all of hudson's reporting regarding SVN etc.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

What I would try. Unfortunately I don't have the time to verify my approach.

A quick way would be to use an parameter and leave a blank if you want to go to head. To check out an older revision, enter "@" plus the revision number as the value for the parameter.

You than just need to add the parameter to the URL for your subversion checkout. I am not sure about the correct syntax. I suspect it is something like `${Parameter_Name}`.

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that one but I can't override the hudson param (or i'm using the wrong param)

Comment: This works. You have to add @$revsionparam on every svn url and revisionparam has to be a String parameter defined for this build.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [Subversion Release Manager](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager) plug-in? Sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: This worked for me. Readers should note the new "Releases" entry in the menus (versus setting a parameter), per documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I made a request:
http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4412

but it didn't go anywhere.

The way we're doing it is having the script call SVN.EXE to get the revision we want.  You can pass in the revision ID as a parameter to SVN.EXE.

Comment: I was heading towards this approach but it will negate all of hudson's tracknig and reporting around source control changes.

what I may be able to do is to add a script that generates the xml source control report as well.  I was hoping to not have to go there since it's by passing key hudson features.