# Is it possible to parameterize subversion repository URL with revision in Hudson?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I have a job in Hudson with Subversion as Source Code Management.
But I do not want always to update working copy to HEAD revision.
I need to have ability to choose SVN revision during start of this job.
It is possible to parameterize build with revision number.
But as far as I can see I cannot use parameter in repository URL.
I can only hardcode revision.
Is it true?

Comment: This sounds like something better handled by your build script rather than Hudson.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078484/build-svn-revision-in-hudson/3078528#3078528

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a String parameter REVISION and then use http://host/path@${REVISION} as repository URL. When starting a build you will then be asked the revision number. You can give a specific revision or HEAD to build the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way it works.  For more information:

In JIRA see:
http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4412

Also, see:
[Can a Parameterized Hudson Build Override the svn revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863949/can-a-parameterized-hudson-build-override-the-svn-revision)

Answer (score 1):

Don't give a URL in Subversion field of Hudson. Just use a single command svn co -rRevision..before the real call of the build script. URL where Revision is defined as a parameter.

Comment: Late, yes, but I really don't recommend doing this. It moves the SVN management out of the build system itself and thus you lose a lot of integration with version history and the current build. It also requires the SVN binaries installed on all build nodes. Anyone reading this, please keep SVN management within Hudson/Jenkins for best results.

Answer (score 1):

The [Subversion Release Manager](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager) plugin might do what you want.

> This plugin allows you to set up a job in Hudson for building specific revisions of a project.

[Hudson-3207](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3207) is the associated Hudson bug.