# build svn revision in hudson

Tags: svn, build, hudson

I have configured a build parameter in Hudson for the revision number. I would like to set a default value so that SVN head is built when the revision number is not specified/changed. `HEAD` does not seem to be working.

This is my subversion repository configured in hudson:

```
http://my_svn_location/trunk@${revision}
```

I see the following error when I build:

```
Location 'http://my_svn_location/trunk@HEAD' does not exist.
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: Isn't this question exact duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863949/can-a-parameterized-hudson-build-override-the-svn-revision/3078277#3078277

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just set your svn location to: `http://my_svn_location/trunk`, hudson will fetch the latest (that is HEAD) revision from the trunk.

So you could set it like this  `http://my_svn_location/trunk${revision}`, and then set revision parameter to `@1234` when you want to fetch a specific version and to empty string ('') when you want the HEAD. Notice that `@` is part of the build parameter. It this what you were looking for?

I am just wondering why you don't always fetch the HEAD?

Comment: thanks juha. that is a simplistic workaround. it just works great. my bad! it did not strike me:)
we need to be able to build svn revisions quickly atleast when build breaks.

Comment: It will not. Hudson will get the last revision that was commited when the build was put in the queue. See http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-1241 for details.